# Hadoop: spark job fails to process small dataset

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

Our trajectory data mining code finished quickly with a 2M data, but it failed with a larger data like 20M due to many failed tasks. We tried to increase the memory but still failed. We have 3 machines cluster with 4 cores and 32GB RAM.
And our configuration is

```
spark.executor.memory 26g 
spark.executor.cores 2 
spark.driver.memory 6g
```

The error information appeared when we try to solve the problem, like "missing an output for shuffle location", "max number of executor failed (3) reached".

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be a memory issue. Did you enable dynamic resource allocation - spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled? That will dynamically increase your executor count till the physical limits are reached. Also, hope you're submitting the job in cluster mode.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation